# I want to split a column into 5 different columns based off its letters and numbers

Tags: r, dataframe, split, multiple-columns

I have a column in my data table that I need to separate into 5 columns.

A typical value is 1A02B1, i would need to separate that into columns of 1,A,02,B,1.

Comment: Possibly related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45804698/split-a-character-to-letters-and-numbers

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to split the column in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32099467/how-to-split-the-column-in-r)

Answer (score 1):

We can create a delimiter with regex and then use `read.csv` from `base R`

```
v1 <- gsub("(?<=[A-Z])(?=[0-9])|(?<=[0-9])(?=[A-Z])", ",", df1$Col1, perl = TRUE)
read.csv(text = v1, header = FALSE)
#  V1 V2 V3 V4 V5
#1  1  A  2  B  1
#2  1  B  3  C  1
```

---

If we need the 3rd column as in the string format, then specify the `colClasses`

```
read.csv(text = v1, header = FALSE, colClasses = c('integer', 
   'character', 'character', 'character', 'integer'),
       stringsAsFactors = FALSE) 
#   V1 V2 V3 V4 V5
#1  1  A 02  B  1
#2  1  B 03  C  1
```

#### data

```
df1 <- data.frame(Col1 = c("1A02B1", "1B03C1"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 1):

**1)** Assuming the input data frame shown in the Note at the end pass a pattern matching digits, non-digits, digits, non-digits and digits to read.pattern which will  separate out the capture groups into fields:

```
library(gsubfn)
pat <- "(\\d+)(\\D+)(\\d+)(\\D+)(\\d+)"
read.pattern(text = DF$x, pattern = pat, colClasses = "character")
```

giving:

```
  V1 V2 V3 V4 V5
1  1  A 02  B  1
```

You may need to omit or change the `colClasses` argument depending on what you want.

**2)** Alternately, `strsplit` could be used to create this matrix:

```
do.call("rbind", strsplit(DF$x, "(?<=\\D)(?=\\d)|(?<=\\d)(?=\\D)", perl = TRUE))
##      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
##  [1,] "1"  "A"  "02" "B"  "1"
```

### Note

```
DF <- data.frame(x = "1A02B1", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```